# Websocket push notification to several JSF applications on Tomcat

Tags: jsf, websocket, tomcat9

I have two JSF applications running on Tomcat.

- localhost:8080/app1/index.xhmtl
- localhost:8080/app2/index.xhmtl

In both index files the same f:websocket tag is placed in the form section.

```
<h:form>

    ...
    ...
    ...

    <f:websocket channel="test" onmessage="socketListener" />
    <h:outputScript>
        function socketListener(message, channel, event) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    </h:outputScript>

</h:form>
```

In both managed beans the same channel is used.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class AppController implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "test")
    private PushContext pushContext;

    public void sendMessage(String p_message)
    {
        pushContext.send(p_message);
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

But when I send a notification via JAVA method `pushContext.send` of app1, the JS method `socketListener` of app2 does not work.

Is it possible to push notification to several JSF applications at once?

Answer (score 3):

The web socket is by default application scoped. Both applications have their own application scope. Both applications don't at all share the same application scope. You see, the application scope is a scope which is, well, tied to a single application. That's because one application is one application. Ah well, I think you get it now :)

You basically want cross-application communication. Standard Java EE API offers JMS for this out the box. But as you're using a barebones Tomcat servlet container, your options are pretty limited. You could [install JMS on Tomcat](https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat%20jms), but better is to migrate to a normal Java EE server. The Java EE variant of Tomcat is [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org/). It already ships JSF, CDI, JMS and more out the box (basically, everything from Java EE), without the need to manually carry around a lot of JAR files via the WAR deployment.

Once having JMS installed in Tomcat, or migrated to a normal Java EE server, then you can follow the instructions in "Cluster design hints" section of the [documentation of OmniFaces `<o:socket>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket#cluster) (the godfather of the `<f:websocket>`).

Comment: Ok, I worried that cross-application notifications aren't possible through websockets. Anyway, thanks for the detailed explanation. I will have a look at TomEE and JMS. And of course at your <o:socket> dokumentation.